# Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Developer.php

Tags: magento-2.1, error

HELP!!!

Tried to upgrade Magento from 2.1.7 to 2.1.8 and now I getting below error, when I load the store.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceInterface in /srv/www/vhosts/mysite/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73

I can't do anything with the **bin/magento** command, it just errors with the above.

Installation steps

```
magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.8 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf ./var/page_cache/*
rm -rf ./var/generation/*
magento setup:upgrade
find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
magento maintenance:disable
service varnish restart
```

I also tried

```
magento setup:di:compile
magento setup:static-content:deploy
service redis restart
service nginx restart
```

Environment

```
openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) (x86_64)
Redis 3.2.3
nginx/1.11.4
varnish-4.1.3 revision 5e3b6d2
mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.27-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Since the magento command is not working I can not restore from the backup I made before trying to upgrade.  I've done many upgrades in the past year and never got this before.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Getting somewhere, I restarted redis assuming that would act as a flush but I needed to start redis-cli and give the flushall command.  Now the magento command is working.

Comment: All fixed.  The key was to flush the redis cache